# Incomplete task before HOST ends with CPU device

Tags: events, opencl, cpu, blocking

I have got only an CPU Core i3 with two cores, so I can only work with CPU, not GPU. I want to test a simple example using OpenCL with a simple add kernel. But here is my problem:

After allocating platform, CPU device, etc, I do the following:

1) clEnqueueNDRange() enqueues a kernel task and assigns an event to the completion of this task using the last parameter.

2) clSetEventCallback() using CL_COMPLETE links the callback function to the aforementioned event.

Normally, the callback function should be called when the task completes. But it doesn't. Indeed, the task in INCOMPLETE at the end event if the host as a lot of stuff to do before ending. Could someone say me why?

Here is my minimal code:

```
/** Simple add kernel */
private static String programSource0 =
    "__kernel void vectorAdd(" +
    "     __global const float *a,"+
    "     __global const float *b, " +
    "     __global float *c)"+
    "{"+
    "    int gid = get_global_id(0);"+
    "    c[gid] = a[gid]+b[gid];"+
    "}";

/** The entry point of this sample */
public static void main(String args[])
{
    /** Callback function */
    EventCallbackFunction kernelCommandEvent = new EventCallbackFunction()
    {
        @Override
        public void function(cl_event event, int event_status, Object user_data)
        {
            System.out.println("Callback: task COMPLETED");
        }
    };

    // Initialize the input data
    int n = 1000000;
    float srcArrayA[] = new float[n];
    float srcArrayB[] = new float[n];
    float dstArray0[] = new float[n];
    Array.fill(srcArrayA, 1,0f);
    Array.fill(srcArrayB, 1,0f);

    // .
    // (hidden) Allocation of my Intel platform, CPU device, kernel, commandQueue, and memory buffer, set the argument to kernel etc...
    // .


    // Set work-item dimensions and execute the kernels
    long globalWorkSize[] = new long[]{n};

    // I pass an event on completion of the command queue.        
    cl_event[] myEventID = new cl_event[1];
    myEventID[0] = new cl_event();
    clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commandQueue, kernel0, 1, null, globalWorkSize, null, 0, null, myEventID[0]);

    // I link the event to the callback function "kernelCommandEvent", and pass 10 as parameter
    clSetEventCallback(myEventID[0], CL_COMPLETE, kernelCommandEvent, new Integer(10));


    // host does some very long stuff !!

    // Normally, my device task should be completed
    int[] ok = new int[1];
    Arrays.fill(ok, 0);
    clGetEventInfo(myEventID[0], CL_EVENT_COMMAND_EXECUTION_STATUS, Sizeof.cl_int, Pointer.to(ok), null);
    if (ok[0] == CL_COMPLETE) System.out.println("Task COMPLETE");else System.out.println("Task INCOMPLETE");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enqueue does not enforce the execution of the task. It just puts it in the queue.

The tasks are executed only if you:

- Force the immediate execution using `clFlush()`.
- Make a blocking call that depends directly or indirectly in that task.

Some drivers can also decide that they will start working on a task even if you did not flush it. But that is implementation dependent. If you want to be sure use `clFlush(commandQueue);`

*Extra:
This behaviour is like that, because the overhead of queuing data to the device can be big, and doing it every Enqueue call may not be efficient if it is called multiple times in a loop. Instead it is defered to the flush or a blocking call, so it can be batched.*

Comment: Ok, thank you for the reply, it worked perfectly. An by the way, I noticed on another computer, that a NVIDIA GPU device does not need this clFlush() call to execute, so this is because what you said about the implementation dependent drivers. So I think that whichever device we use, it is a good think to always call clFlush() function, in order to be sure the task is being executed, right? Thank you very much anyway DarkZeros

Comment: Depends, for example in the CPU only case. Making all the processing at the blocking call saves some time, since it minimizes the amount of context switches of your app. While in GPU devices, it is useful to start working as faster as possible.

Comment: So in the case where several command queues belong to several different contexts, it is more convenient to perform all calls to clEnqueueNDRange(), and then call only once clFlush() if I understood correctly?

Comment: My recommendation is: You should perform clFlush() after the first Enqueue (so that the system starts working as fast as possible). Then add all the other enqueues, and do the blocking reads/waits. Those later ones will perform another implicit flush. So you get the best of 2 worlds, fast startup and batching as much as possible.